# Android Webview Media Playback Android Level 16

Tags: android, html, video, webview, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I am trying to play a video using HTML5 media tag on Android 4.1.x I can get it to play on other API (both above and below) level, and I know about `getMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture` in API level 17+. However specifically on 4.1.x I can't get the video to play without user gesture. I know about setting hardwareAccelerated=true on my activity and using custom ChromeClient.

Looking at [4.1 webkit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit/+/android-4.1.1_r6.1/Source/WebCore/html/HTMLMediaElement.cpp#188)  source code it seems that even on 4.1.x mediaPlayback requires user gesture, even though on that API level I can't use requiresUserGesture(true) in my activity.

My HTML code is basically as below, and the video will *not* play unless I tap on the screen. If I listen to all the events I see it go loadstart => durationchange => loadedmetadata => loadedata => stalled.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    video.load();
    video.play();
  }, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="video" src="file:///sdcard/example/file.mp4" preload="auto"></video>
</video>
</body>
</html>
```